# How to install ubuntu on ASUS FX553V? (? = D or E I don't know) with firmware bug

Tags: kubuntu, asus, 18.04

I already have ubuntu on my laptop.

I'd like to install kubuntu but when I boot the computer I have some issues.

I don't even know how to find if my PC is ASUS FX553VE or FX553VD.

Can you helm me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions in this page:
http://pclub.in/2017/01/06/Linux-on-Asus-ROG.html

It worked for me.

Comment: Do I have to update the bios first? The screenshot appears at the beginning of the boot process

Comment: Just switch off Secure Boot and Fast Boot and follow those instructions. Both the errors (TSC_DEADLINE and ACPI Error) should not show up. As far as I know, my stock BIOS is the latest BIOS (Checked with ASUS website).

Comment: It did work fine. Thanks. A small question though: now kubuntu does not shutdown. As soon as I shutdown it hangs forever and I have no control on the keybord. Only way to shutdown is to hold down the power butto

Comment: I don't know about Kubuntu, but on Ubuntu it works just fine. Maybe try reinstalling Kubuntu with acpi_osi=Linux alone in grub options on Try Kubuntu . That's what I did on Ubuntu. I'm having no problems now.

Comment: I solved installing the correct nvidia drivers. With the default drivers installed by kubuntu, the shutdown procedure freezes.