# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't boot in UEFI mode, even from USB in live mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, acpi

I have faced numerous issues with Ubuntu 18.04 lately, messed up some stuff and finally decided to reinstall it. I managed to do so in Legacy Support mode first, but it seems that in order to make dual boot worked I need to change the boot mode to UEFI. Unfortunately, when I do so, my Ubuntu system doesn't open. I wanted to reinstall it once again, in UEFI mode this time, but it results in the following error:

[image]

This seems like a graphics issue as I can hear the sound when I turn up or turn down volume using functional keys. Unfortunately, this is the case for both the *Try Ubuntu* and *Install Ubuntu* options. How can I reinstall Ubuntu and fix all of this?

I have deleted all partitions connected to Windows, but the issue persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus FX553VD laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031573/cant-boot-ubuntu-18-04-on-my-asus-fx553vd-laptop)

Comment: Yes, it helped me to install Ubuntu on UEFI boot, thanks a bunch! Still have issues with recovering after suspension, but it may need another solution.

Comment: That would be another separate question. Otherwise it would be too broad and degrade the searchability of this site as too broad questions often do.

Comment: I get it. I'll post a new question then.